# Elementary derivation in a very stingy logical calculus

Tags: logic

Following up on a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229763/) at MathOverflow, I am trying to understand the logical calculus defined [here](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/3843/1/3843.pdf) (p.183) by Buchholz and Wainer.

I want to prove $0=0+0$.

(I *can* prove $0+0=0$: I start with $\{0+0=0, 0+0\neq 0\}$ (by the "logical axiom"), from which I conclude that $\{0+0=0, \exists x\ x+0 \neq x\}$. On the other hand, from the first "$+$" axiom and the $\forall$ rule I can get $\{0+0=0, \forall x\ x+0=x\}$. Then I apply cut. QED)

The problem is that the authors (top of the page) restrict *terms* to include only variables, the constant $0$, and the successor function $\mathrm S$. Meaning, no "$+$" or "$\cdot$". So apparently, the $t$ in the $\exists$ rule can only stand for terms of this form.

If $t$ could hold arbitrary terms then I could get from $0+0=0$ to $0=0+0$ using the axiom "$\Gamma,x\neq y, y=x$": I start with $\{0\neq 0+0 \wedge 0+0=0, 0=0+0 \vee 0+0\neq 0\}$ (by the logical axiom); then, letting $t=0+0$, I get to $\{\exists x\ 0\neq x \wedge x=0, 0=0+0 \vee 0+0\neq 0\}$, etc.

But this is cheating, apparently.

Comment: I think the restriction is only intended to apply to the $t_i$ that appear as the operands of primitive functions symbols, $+$, $-$ etc. I.e., "each term" in the paragraph at the top of the page means "each of the terms $t_i$". (Restricting nesting of function symbols is often technically convenient.) Does the rest of it make sense with that reading?

Comment: I didn't think of that. So, for example, you're supposed to represent $w=x+y+z$ as $x+y=u \wedge w=u+z$?

Comment: You need to existentially quantify over the variable $u$ you've introduced, but that's the idea, I suspect.

Comment: If we allow the $t$ in the $\exists$ rule to take values such as $x+y$, then the fourth "$+$" axiom seems redundant, since it would follow from the symmetry and transitivity of "=" (second and third "$=$" axioms). I think.

Comment: Doesn't your objection to the fourth "+" axiom stand regardless of how you read the $\exists$ rule? (You shoudn't need to reason about any quantifiers to do the deduction you have in mind.)

Comment: My conjecture about what was meant is wrong. See the middle of p. 189, where they state explicitly the constraint on the $t$ in the $\exists$ rule. It is indeed a very stingy logic. Sorry for the red herring.

Comment: Returning to your question $\ddot{\smile}$. Can't you prove $0 = 0 + 0$ by instantiating $x$ to $0$ in the first "+" rule giving $0 + 0 = 0$ and then using symmetry of equality?

Comment: Symmetry of equality is only given for lone variables, not for expressions with "$+$" in them!

Comment: It says the axioms are all *substitution instances* of ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  In fact, you can't even ask the question: 0=0+0 isn't a formula.

This is a subtle point: + isn't a function symbol in this system.  The *graph* of addition is a *relation symbol*, so "x+y=z" is an atomic formula with three variables, and "0+0=0" is also an atomic formula (which happens to be deducible from the first defining axiom for addition).

This is definitely confusing: the symbol "=" means both the equality relation and is used as part of indicating various other relation symbols.  (This is an unusual notation choice I haven't seen elsewhere, probably because it's so confusing.)

Comment: You mean $*+*=*$ denotes a ternary relation? And this system has no functions besides $\mathrm S$?

Comment: And what would be a less confusing way of doing the same thing?

Comment: @GabrielNivasch: For your first question, yes (this is what it says at the top of p. 183).  I think the more common thing is to introduce a name for the graph of the addition function---say "Axyz" for the formula meaning "x+y=z".